# import caffe, error _message.so

Tags: macos, caffe

I installed caffe from source code on my Mac os x, but when I type this command:

`python -c "import caffe"`

I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/junhao.wen/Hao/Docker/Caffe/Caffe_source/caffe/python/caffe/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .pycaffe import Net, SGDSolver, NesterovSolver, AdaGradSolver, RMSPropSolver, AdaDeltaSolver, AdamSolver
  File "/Users/junhao.wen/Hao/Docker/Caffe/Caffe_source/caffe/python/caffe/pycaffe.py", line 15, in <module>
    import caffe.io
  File "/Users/junhao.wen/Hao/Docker/Caffe/Caffe_source/caffe/python/caffe/io.py", line 8, in <module>
    from caffe.proto import caffe_pb2
  File "/Users/junhao.wen/Hao/Docker/Caffe/Caffe_source/caffe/python/caffe/proto/caffe_pb2.py", line 7, in <module>
    from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
  File "/Users/junhao.wen/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/protobuf-3.1.0-py2.7-macosx-10.6-x86_64.egg/google/protobuf/descriptor.py", line 46, in <module>
    from google.protobuf.pyext import _message
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/junhao.wen/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/protobuf-3.1.0-py2.7-macosx-10.6-x86_64.egg/google/protobuf/pyext/_message.so, 2): Symbol not found: __ZNK6google8protobuf10TextFormat17FieldValuePrinter10PrintBytesERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE
  Referenced from: /Users/junhao.wen/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/protobuf-3.1.0-py2.7-macosx-10.6-x86_64.egg/google/protobuf/pyext/_message.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/junhao.wen/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/protobuf-3.1.0-py2.7-macosx-10.6-x86_64.egg/google/protobuf/pyext/_message.so
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated:)
Thanks in advance

Comment: please format your question

Comment: have you iinstalled and compiled all prerequisites? specifically protobuf?

Comment: Yes, I have compiled them, but I think maybe because when I install the python dependencies, I can not install leveldb with my anaconda pip, but i do have leveldb with brew, here is the error:   
    cc1plus: warning: command line option '-Wstrict-prototypes' is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
    cc1plus: error: -Werror=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future: no option -Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

Comment: I dont know how to format my question, it said that comment only edit in five minutes, this is really complicated

Comment: see [these instructions](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: What is your PROTOCOL_BUFFERS_PYTHON_IMPLEMENTATION environment variable set to if it is set to anything?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the Python path is pointing to $CAFFE_HOME/Python